# Prove of refute uniform convergence of integral.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence

I can't prove (or refute) uniform convergence of

$$
\int_{1}^{+\infty} \arctan\frac{2y}{x^2+y^2}dx,\;y\in\mathbb{R}
$$

I tried Weierstrass M-test, but failed. Can't find the solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\arctan(\cdot)$ is increasing on $[0,1]$ and for $x \geqslant 1$ and $y > 0$ we have

$$0 \leqslant \frac{2y}{x^2 + y^2} \leqslant \frac{2xy}{x^2 + y^2} \leqslant 1$$

Thus,

$$\sup_{y \in \mathbb{R^+}}\int_n^\infty  \arctan\frac{2y}{x^2 + y^2} \, dx > \sup_{y \in \mathbb{R^+}}\int_n^{2n} \arctan\frac{2y}{x^2 + y^2} \, dx \\ > \sup_{y \in \mathbb{R^+}}\left(n\arctan\frac{2y}{(2n)^2 + y^2}\right) \\ \geqslant  n\arctan\frac{2n}{4n^2 + n^2 } \\=  n\arctan\frac{2}{5n } $$

Using the Taylor expansion $\arctan x = x + \mathcal{O}(x^3)$ for $x \in (-1,1]$ we have

$$\sup_{y \in \mathbb{R^+}}\int_n^\infty  \arctan\frac{2y}{x^2 + y^2} \, dx > n\left[\frac{2}{5n} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^3} \right)\right] \\ = \frac{2}{5} + \mathcal{O} \left(\frac{1}{n^2} \right)$$

Since the RHS does not converge to $0$ as $n \to \infty$, the convergence of the improper integral is not uniform for $y \in [0,\infty)$ and, consequently, for $y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The proof is the same showing convergence is not uniform on any interval where $y$ is unbounded to the right.

Comment: In $$\arctan\frac{2y}{(2n)^2+y^2}\int_{n}^{2n}1\;dx$$ $\frac{2y}{(2n)^2+y^2}\int_{n}^{2n}1\;dx$ is argument of $\arctan$ in this case?

Comment: No I pulled out the $C= \arctan( 2y/ ((2n)^2 +y ^2)$ (which does not depend on $x$) from inside the integral.  It just means $\int_n^{2n} C \, dx  = C(2n-n) = Cn$.

Comment: But why $\arctan\frac{2yn}{(2n)^2+y^2}$ instead of $n\arctan\frac{2y}{(2n)^2+y^2}$?

Comment: You are right. That is a mistake from the earlier answer before you added arctan.  I can fix it. Give me some time. Thanks

Comment: @guarandoo:  OK I fixed the answer.  Good job catching that mistake.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

$$\DeclareMathOperator\sgn{sgn}
f(A,y)=\int_1^A \frac {2y\, \mathrm dx}{x^2+y^2} = \int_1^A \frac {2y\cdot y}{y^2} \cdot \frac {\mathrm d(x/y)}{(x/y)^2 + 1} = 2\int_{1/y}^{A/y} \frac {\mathrm d u}{1+u^2} = 2\arctan (A/y) - 2\arctan (1/y) \to \pi \sgn y - 2\arctan (1/y) [A\to +\infty, y \neq 0], 
$$
and $f(A,0) = 0$. So the limit function $g(y) = 2\cdot 1_{\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}} (y)(\pi \sgn y - \arctan (1/y))$.

Now consider
$$
\sup_{y \in \mathbb R^*} \vert f(A,y) - g(y) \vert = \sup_{\mathbb R^*} \vert 2 \arctan (A/y) - \pi \sgn y\vert = \sgn_{\mathbb R^+} \vert 2\arctan (A/y) - \pi \vert \geqslant \vert 2\arctan (A/A) -\pi \vert =\frac\pi 2,
$$
thus the integral does not converge uniformly.

Comment: Ummm… question changed.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's my bad.

Comment: @guarandoo Don't mind. I forgot to refresh the page in time.